# Summarise and calculate the items specifically in the dataset using proc sql

Tags: sas

My dataset and attempt

```
data mydata;
input Category $ Item $;
datalines;
A 1
A 1 
A 2
B 3
B 1
;

proc sql;
create table mytable as 
    select *, count(Category) as Total_No_in_Category, count(Category)-count(item, "3") as No_of_not_3_in_the_same_category from mydata
    group by Category;
run;
```

Result

```
Category     No_of_not_3_in_the_same_category   Total_No_in_Category


  A                      3                          3
  A                      3                          3
  A                      3                          3
  B                      2                          2
  B                      2                          1
```

My expected result

```
 Category   No_of_not_3_in_the_same_ category   Total_No_in_Category
    A                          2                       3
    B                          1                       2
```

I wonder how to achieve the expected result using only proc SQL. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two argument `COUNT(item, "3")` function call is not an summary function.  That causes **all rows** from original table to be **automatically** remerged with the aggregate computation (those `count()`). The remerge is a proprietary feature of SAS `Proc SQL` and not part of the ANSI Standard for SQL.

You appear to want the number of unique non-3 item values, so you will need a

```
COUNT(DISTINCT ...expression...)
```

in the query.  The `...expression...` can be a `case` clause that transforms `item="3"` to a **null** value by not having an `else` part of the `case` clause.

Example:

```
create table want as
select
  category
  , count(*) as freq
  , count(distinct case when item ne "3" then item end) as n_unq_item_not_3
  from mydata
  group by category
  ;
```